# Child re-rendering because of function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

I'm having trouble navigating these concepts where a child keeps re-rendering because I'm passing it a function from the parent. This parent function references an editor's value, draftjs.

```
function Parent() {
    const [doSomethingValue, setDoSomethingValue] = React.useState("");
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
        EditorState.createEmpty()
    );

    const editorRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const doSomething = () => {
        // get draftjs editor current value and make a fetch call
        let userResponse = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("\u0001");

        // do something with userResponse
        setDoSomethingValue(someValue);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child doSomething={doSomething} />
            <Editor
             ref={editorRef}
             editorState={editorState}
             onChange={setEditorState}
             placeholder="Start writing..." />
            <AnotherChild doSomethingValue={doSomethingValue}
        <React.Fragment>
    }

}
```

My Child component is simply a button that calls the parent's doSomething and thats it.

doSomething does its thing and then makes a change to the state which is then passed to AnotherChild.

My problem is that anytime the editorState is updated (which is every time you type within the editor), my Child component re-renders. Isn't that unnecessary? And if so, how could I avoid this?

If I was passing my Child component a string and leveraged React.Memo, it does not re-render unless the string changes.

So what am I missing with passing a function to the child? *Should my child be re-rendering everytime?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React works on reference change detection to re-render components.

`Child.js`: Wrap it under [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) so it becomes [Pure Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

```
const Child = ({doSomething}) => <button onClick={doSomething}>Child Button Name</button>;
export default React.memo(Child);
```

`Parent.js -> doSomething`: On every (re)render, callbacks are also recreated. Make use of [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) so that your function is not recreated on every render.

```
const doSomething = React.useCallback(() => {
    let userResponse = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("\u0001");
    setDoSomethingValue(someValue);
}, [editorState]);
```

**Side Note**

On broader lines, `memo` is HOC and makes a component Pure Component. `useMemo` is something which cache the output of the function. Whereas `useCallback` caches the instance of the function.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your component to be re-rendered every time your parent is re-rendered, you should take a look at [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

This function will only recalculate its value (in your case, your component) whenever its second argument changes (here, the only thing it depends on, `doSomething()`).

```
function Parent() {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
        EditorState.createEmpty()
    );

    const editorRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const doSomething = () => {
        // get draftjs editor current value and make a fetch call
        let userResponse = editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("\u0001");

        // do something with userResponse
    }

    const childComp = useMemo(() => <Child doSomething={doSomething} />, [doSomething])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {childComp}
            <Editor
             ref={editorRef}
             editorState={editorState}
             onChange={setEditorState}
             placeholder="Start writing..." />
        <React.Fragment>
    }
}
```

If `doSomething` does not change, your component does not re-render.

You may also want to use `useCallback` for your function if it is doing heavy calculations, to avoid having it re-compiled every time your component renders: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: So doSomething is technically changing since userResponse is changing, no? So this re-render is justified?

Comment: Nope, the code within your function isn't executed unless the function is called, useMemo does not change its behavior based on what the function contains or return, just its reference. Try it out by putting a simple `console.log` within your child comp, you will notice it is not called even if its parent re-renders

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into `PureComponent`, `useMemo`, or `shouldComponentUpdate`

I would also add, instead of passing down the function to do the rendering of a top level component, pass the value and define the function later down in the component tree.

Comment: I added more to my question. The reason why I left doSomething in Parent because it's setting a state value which another component, AnotherChild, is using. So would I still want to pass the value and function later down in the component tree?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid unnecessary re-renders, you can use React.memo and the hook useCallback. Take a look at the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-river-zd1y6?file=/src/App.js).
The button1 is always re-rendered because it take a callback that is not memoized with useCallback and the button2 is just rendered the first time even if the state of the parent has changed (take a look at the console to check the re-renders). You have to use React.memo in the Child component that is the responsible to render the buttons.

I hope it helps.